# Is my proof clear/correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{d|n}\phi (d)=n:$

**Lemma:** $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab)$ if $(a,b)=1$.

*Proof (edited):*  $\phi(n)$ is the number of generators of $C_n$. In particular the number of generators of $C_{ab}$ is $\phi(ab)$. Note that
if $(a,b)=1$ then $C_{ab}\cong C_a\times C_b$.

For any generators $\alpha,\beta$ of $C_a,C_b$ respectively, $(\alpha,\beta)$ generates $C_{ab}$, since: $$\text{ord}(\alpha,\beta)=\text{lcm}(\text{ord} \,\alpha,\text{ord}\,\beta)=\text{lcm}(a,b)=ab$$ The number of pairs of generators $(\alpha,\beta)$ is $\phi(a)\phi(b)$ which proves the claim.

*Note* (in respone to DonAntonio's comment): WLOG take $x$ where $\langle x\rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $C_a\;($so $\text{ord}\,x<a)$ and $y\in C_b$. By Lagrange $\text{ord}\,x|a,\text{ord}\,y|b\Rightarrow (\text{ord}\,x,\text{ord}\,y)=1$ so:

$$\text{ord}(x,y)=\text{ord}\,x\cdot\text{ord}\, y<a\,\text{ord}\, y\leq ab$$

Hence $(x,y)$ cannot possibly generate $C_{ab}$.

**Proposition:** $\sum_{d|n}\phi (d)=n$

*Proof:* By induction. $n=1:\;\sum_{d|1}\phi (d)=\phi(1)=1$. Assume $\sum_{d|k}\phi (d)=k$ holds for $n< k$. If $k=p^n,\;p$ prime, then: $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{d|k}\phi(d)&=\sum_{j=0}^n \phi(p^j)=1+\sum_{j=1}^n (p^j-p^{j-1})=p^n\end{aligned}$$ and we are done. Otherwise write $k=p^mq$ for some prime $p$, where $m$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $k$ and $q>1$. Then $q<k$ and by our lemma: $$k=p^m q=\left(\sum_{d|p^m}\phi(d)\right)\left(\sum_{d|q}\phi(d)\right)=\sum_{j=0}^m\phi(p^j)\sum_{d|q} \phi(d)=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{d|q}\phi(p^j d)$$
Since each divisor of $k$ can be written $p^jd$ for some $d|q$ and $0\leq j\leq m$ this sum is over all divisors of $k$ (indeed, none are counted more than once). Hence $\sum_{d|k}\phi(d)=k$ and we are done.

---

I know there are other proofs of this, and that most are simpler, but this is what came most naturally to me when I set the problem to myself as an exercise. Can I just check that it works and that the argument is sufficiently clear? Are there any improvements I can make?

**Edit:** I realise now that it is a little odd to use a group theoretic argument for the lemma but not for the proposition $-$ this is because my initial attempt at proving the lemma (purely number theoretic) was flawed: after this was pointed out by benh, the current proof is what came to mind. I will leave the second part as it was.

Comment: In your lemma's proof, how do you get the third equality? I mean, how is it obvious that the second line equals $\;\varphi(p^nq^m)\;$ ? I think writing "inclusion/exclusion principle" doesn't make the cut here...

Comment: The lemma's new proof could be called "circular": how do you prove that $\;C_{ab}\cong C_a\times C_b\;$ ? Besides this, in the last part you show that every pair $\;(\alpha,\beta)\;$ of generators of $\;C_a\,,\,C_b\;$ resp. gives us a generator of $\;C_{ab}\;$, but then this only proves $\;\varphi(a)\varphi(b)\le\varphi(ab)\;$ . What about the other direction, i.e.: showing that every generator of $\;C_{a,b}\;$ has this form?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't think that it's circular. You only need the Euclidean Algorithmus to show that there is a set of generators in the image of $C_a \times C_b \rightarrow C_{ab}$ in order to conclude that it's an isomorphism, as we are in the finite setting. No need for $\varphi$ here. I agree with your second remark about the other direction, but I think as the OP seems to know some algebra it's clear that the preimage of a generator is again a generator so that's easy to fix.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks, good point. I've added a justification. As for $C_{ab}\cong C_a\times C_b$, it was not proved using any knowledge of $\phi$, in my course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of the Proposition looks good.

For the proof of your Lemma you seem to have the right idea. But if one is nitpicky the proof is incomplete: The reason is, that **you have shown the assertion only for prime powers**. However the step from products of two prime powers two products of more prime powers is not an induction step, because you can't just plug in another number instead of the prime power. So just saying "the claim follows inductively" is arguably not enough.

Instead you could give a general formula for $\phi(n)$ and use it for a very short proof or you give an argument as you have done in the last part of your proof of the Proposition.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've tried something a little different for the lemma now.

Comment: Hello user118224. Being an algebraist, I love your idea of using cyclic groups and generators for this :) Beautiful proof of the Lemma now!

Comment: Oh brilliant! Thank you again for your help! :)